A primeira, na primeira ou da primeira?
Qual das seguintes frases está correta:


A primeira vez que fui a Roma eu não visitei o Vaticano.
Na primeira vez que fui a Roma eu não visitei o Vaticano.
Da primeira vez que fui a Roma eu não visitei o Vaticano.


Acredito que seja a segunda opção, mas não tenho certeza. Qual parte da norma culta trata esse tipo de frase?

A primeira e segunda opções são de uso corrente, e a segunda é aquela que eu usaria.  No Português falado, no entanto, ouve-se as três e não se presta muita atenção se você falou da, na, ou a.

Como poderia estar errado dizer: A primeira vez que fiz sei-lá-o-que etc?

A primeira opção não está correcta.
"A primeira vez que fui a Roma" é uma locução que, por si só, age como um substantivo. Por isso, pode ser uma oração subordinada substantiva. Orações subordinadas substantivas podem ser, principalmente, subjetivas ou objetivas. A frase seguinte "Eu não visitei o Vaticano" já possui sujeito e predicado completos, portanto não admite uma oração substantiva. Possivelmente trata-se da audição da expressão "À primeira vez" mal convertida à escrita.
Para que a locução supracitada possa ser inserida na frase, ela deve incluir uma preposição a fim de que forme uma locução adverbial.
Seria então a segunda opção:

Na primeira vez que fui a Roma, não visitei o Vaticano.


"Em [a primeira vez que fui a Roma]-ADV, não-ADV visitei-VERB o Vaticano-OBJ."

Sobre o uso da crase em locuções adverbiais, vide: https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/ha-crase-nas-locucoes-adverbiais.html
A terceira frase, com a preposição "de", a qual não é padrão em locuções adverbiais temporais, é possível mas não recomendaria. Provavelmente trata-se de uma infecção da expressão "De primeira", como em "Passei na avaliação de primeira".
Ademais, o correto mesmo seria

Na primeira vez em que fui a Roma, não visitei o Vaticano.

Chama-se atenção ao facto de que nem toda expressão adverbial requer preposições, como é o caso dos dias da semana:

Domingo fui ao mercado.

Como se explica nesta consulta do ciberdúvidas. Um aparte: o estimado consultor também afirma que "Num dia" não é aceitável ao mesmo nível que "Um dia", enquanto que eu discordo, sendo ambos compreensíveis e não violantes de regras morfossintáticas — em face de vários outros impropérios linguísticos que se defendem hoje em português.

A única coisa que faltava na segunda era a vírgula.

@Lambie Sim, por isso a incluí. Ainda assim, se não me engano, a vírgula separativa de locuções adverbiais é opcional, embore configure um estilo mais claro.
